# Send a test system workflow message

Tags: system-workflow-messages

We have done some updates to these and wonder if it is possible to send a preview of them so we can see how they look? I can't see any options to send a test message? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you enable the "Message Admin" built-in extension there is a semi-hidden icon on the message template edit form that gives you a preview but note that it doesn't use your configured settings it uses some sample config.

Depending which message it is you can do an online signup in test mode, e.g. under Manage Contribution Pages each one has a link for test mode. The emails will still go out but you'll be able to complete the form using the processor's test cards without making a real contribution.

There is also the [Better Message Templates](https://civicrm.org/extensions/better-message-templates) extension which has a preview option but you need to manually create sample data.

Comment: Really helpful and the Better message templates works well.